# validation when updating a sqlalchemy orm is not working

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have this class:

```
class User(base):
    __tablename__='User'
    name = Column(.......

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    @validates('name')
    def validate_name(self, key, name):
        if blah blah blah:
            return name
        else:
            raise exception.....
```

create a new user and store him in database...

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    user = User('foo')
    session.add(user)
    session.commit() #validation works here
```

when updating the user:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    user = session.query(User).filter_by(name=='foo').first()
    user.name = 'bar'
    session.add(user)
    session.commit() #validation not working here
```

when storing a new user, the validation works
but when updating an existing user, validation not works

Q: how to validate a table column when updating its value using @validates?

Thanks :)

Comment: Works for me - without a proper validation function this issue isn't reproducible, so the question should be closed.

Answer (score -1):

`sqlalchemy.orm.validates` works properly and it fires up on insert or update.

```
class Account(Base):
   # ...rest
   password = Column('password', String(50))

   @validates('password')
   def hash_password(self, key, val):
      salt = bcrypt.gensalt()
      encodedpw = val.encode()
      hashedpw = bcrypt.hashpw(encodedpw, salt)
      return hashedpw.decode()
```

Heres how I update the `Account`

```
acc db_session.get(Account, '<account_id>')
acc.password = '<new_passw>'
db_session.commit()
```